# Actionscript 3 and defaultTextFormat

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

This is not a big deal, but I'm wondering if I discovered a bug in AS3.  The following code works fine (trackName is a TextField):

```
trackname.defaultTextFormat = format;
trackname.text = "   " + name;
trackname.width = width;
trackname.height = height;
trackname.textColor = color;
trackname.border = true;
trackname.x = x;
trackname.y = y;
```

However, if I assign the defaultTextFormat at the end:

```
trackname.text = "   " + name;
trackname.width = width;
trackname.height = height;
trackname.textColor = color;
trackname.border = true;
trackname.x = x;
trackname.y = y;
trackname.defaultTextFormat = format;
```

The format that is displayed is different- in fact, I'd guess it really is the default text format. Is there a separate thread that does the assignment, and therefore needs to be at the beginning to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> Use the TextField.defaultTextFormat property to apply formatting BEFORE you add text to the TextField, and the setTextFormat() method to add formatting AFTER you add text to the TextField.
>
> The TextFormat properties are null by default because if you don't provide values for the properties, Flash Player uses its own default formatting.

Source:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html

Comment: Interesting.  AS3 gets quite bizarre.